# How do I dynamically register variables with Ansible?

Tags: yaml, ansible

I want to define an Ansible role and register dynamic variables:

```
---
- name: Check for {{ package }}
  stat: path=/opt/packages/{{ package }}
  register: "{{ package | regex_replace('-', '_') }}"
- name: Install {{ package }} {{ package_version }}
  command: "custom-package-installer {{ package }} {{ package_version }}"
  when: "not {{ package | regex_replace('-', '_') }}.stat.exists"
```

Usage looks like this:

```
- include: install_package.yml package=foo package_version=1.2.3
```

However, Ansible doesn't recognise the conditional:

```
TASK: [example | Install foo 1.2.3] *********************************** 
fatal: [my-server] => error while evaluating conditional: not foo.stat.exists

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

How can I define variables dynamically, expanding the `{{` `}}`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512443/register-dynamic-variable-names-in-ansible-playbook

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to register a dynamic variable. There is no way for a placeholder `{{ var }}` in register. However there is a much cleaner way to perform what I think you are trying to achieve: [Ansible: it's a fact](http://jpmens.net/2012/07/15/ansible-it-s-a-fact/).

Short summary:

You can write a simple script which prints JSON like:

```
#!/bin/python #or /bin/bash or any other executable
....

print """{ "ansible_facts": {
              "available_packages": ["a", "b", "c"]
               }
          }"""
```

and put it into your local facts folder on the machine (as executable script with `.fact` ending):

```
Your second task would then look like:

- name: Install {{ package }} {{ package_version }}
  command: "custom-package-installer {{ package }} {{ package_version }}"
  when: "not package in ansible_facts['available_packages']"
```

[Ansible docs on facts](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a dynamic variable in this case, doing:

```
---
- name: Check for {{ package }}
  stat: path=/opt/packages/{{ package }}
  register: current_package

- name: Install {{ package }} {{ package_version }}
  command: "custom-package-installer {{ package }} {{ package_version }}"
  when: not current_package.stat.exists
```

is perfectly fine...

Comment: Does that work even if there are multiple includes of the package?

Answer (score 0):

Like many things, this is possible if you really want to do it, but natively in ansible it is not supported.

That said, ansible is written in python and you can call the playbooks from directly within python code.  The way that I do this is to dynamically generate the playbooks and then execute them in a two step process.

In effect, it is like having dynamic playbooks.  So to summarise...

1. Generate playbook using whatever logic is appropriate.
2. Execute playbook using ansible.