# Register Variables in Loop in an Ansible Playbook

Tags: linux, scripting, automation, ansible

I have two ansible tasks as follows

```
  tasks:
 - shell: ifconfig -a | sed 's/[ \t].*//;/^\(lo\|\)$/d'
   register: var1
 - debug: var=var1

 - shell: ethtool -i {{ item }} | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22
   with_items: var1.stdout_lines
   register: var2
 - debug: var=var2
```

which is used to get a list of interfaces in a machine (linux) and get the bus address for each. I have one more task as follows in tha same playbook

```
 - name: Binding the interfaces
   shell: echo {{ item.item }}
   with_flattened: var2.results
   register: var3
```

which I expect to iterate over value from var2 and then print the bus numbers.

var2.results is as follows

```
"var2": {
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i br0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.005778",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:47.122203",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i br0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "br0:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:47.116425",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "",
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i enp13s0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.005862",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:47.359749",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i enp13s0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "enp13s0:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:47.353887",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "0d:00.0",
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i enp14s0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.005805",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:47.576674",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i enp14s0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "enp14s0:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:47.570869",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "0e:00.0",
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i enp15s0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.005873",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:47.875058",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i enp15s0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "enp15s0:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:47.869185",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "0f:00.0",
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i enp5s0f1: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.005870",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:48.112027",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i enp5s0f1: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "enp5s0f1:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:48.106157",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "05:00.1",
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i enp5s0f2: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.005863",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:48.355733",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i enp5s0f2: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "enp5s0f2:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:48.349870",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "05:00.2",
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i enp5s0f3: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.005829",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:48.591244",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i enp5s0f3: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "enp5s0f3:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:48.585415",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "05:00.3",
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i enp9s0f0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.005943",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:48.910992",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i enp9s0f0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "enp9s0f0:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:48.905049",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "09:00.0",
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i enp9s0f1: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.005863",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:49.143706",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i enp9s0f1: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "enp9s0f1:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:49.137843",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "09:00.1",
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i lo: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.005856",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:49.386044",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i lo: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "lo:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:49.380188",
            "stderr": "Cannot get driver information: Operation not supported",
            "stdout": "",
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i virbr0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.005859",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:49.632356",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i virbr0: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "virbr0:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:49.626497",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "",
            "warnings": []
        },
        {
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "ethtool -i virbr0-nic: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
            "delta": "0:00:00.024850",
            "end": "2015-04-14 20:29:49.901539",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "ethtool -i virbr0-nic: | grep bus-info | cut -b 16-22",
                "module_name": "shell"
            },
            "item": "virbr0-nic:",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2015-04-14 20:29:49.876689",
            "stderr": "",
            "stdout": "",
            "warnings": []
        }
    ]
```

My objective is to get the value of stdout in each item above for example ("stdout": "09:00.0") . I tried giving something like

```
     - name: Binding the interfaces
       shell: echo {{ item.item.stdout}}
       with_flattened: var2.results
#       with_indexed_items: var2.results
       register: var3
```

But this is not giving the bus values in stdout correctly. Appreciate help in listing the variable of variable value in task as given below when the second variable is and indexed list. I am trying to avoid direct index numbering such as item[0] because the number of interfaces are dynamic and direct indexing may result in unexpected outcomes.

Thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

> Variables registered for a task that has `with_items` have different format, they contain results for all items.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tags: s21
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    images:
      - foo
      - bar
  tasks:
    - shell: "echo result-{{item}}"
      register: "r"
      with_items: "{{images}}"

    - debug: var=r

    - debug: msg="item.item={{item.item}}, item.stdout={{item.stdout}}, item.changed={{item.changed}}"
      with_items: "{{r.results}}"

    - debug: msg="Gets printed only if this item changed - {{item}}"
      when: "{{item.changed == true}}"
      with_items: "{{r.results}}"
```

Source: [Register variables in with_items loop in Ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512443/register-dynamic-variable-names/29564339#29564339)

Comment: @user3364247 you tried using `with_items` instead of flattened to loop over `var2.results`? Can you post new code?

Comment: Actually your solution is correct, but to get what I wanted, modified the code like following

Comment: Your solution is correct. But to get what I wanted, I modified the code as follows      - shell: echo  {{item.stdout}}
       with_items:  var2.results
       when: item.stdout != ""
       register: var3
     - debug: var=var3

Comment: @user3364247 yes, that's what I my answer says.

Comment: In order for this to work with ansible version 2.2.1.0
you have to change  `with_items: images`  to `with_items: "{{images}}"` in your first task