# Interating through multiple files on a webserver in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a project that requires me to grab the content of multiple files from a remote server and pass into a file.

Here is task i created to accomplish the goal:

```
- name: check content
  uri:
   url: http://172.16.2.3/file1
   method: GET
   return_content: yes
  register: file1

  - name: print content
    debug: msg={{file1.content}}
```

Debugging the content shows the following

```
ok: [172.16.2.4] => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "testcontent11111\n"
```

However because i have to loop through multiple files, i tried the following:

```
- name: check content
  uri:
   url: http://172.16.2.3/{{item.url}}
   method: GET
   return_content: yes
   register: {{item.register}}
  with_items:
  - { url: 'file1', register: 'file1' }

  - name: print content
    debug: msg={{file1.content}}
```

Debugging the above content unfortunately yields the following in my output

```
FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'file1' is undefined\
```

Any idea how i can write the second task to accomplish the goal of the first one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Register variables in with\_items loop in Ansible playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512443/register-variables-in-with-items-loop-in-ansible-playbook) - and there is no way to register variables with arbitrary names in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to register var with dynamic name.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop

```
- name: check content
  uri:
   url: http://172.16.2.3/{{item.url}}
   method: GET
   return_content: yes
   register: files
  with_items:
    - { url: 'file1', register: 'file1' }
    - { url: 'file2', register: 'file2' }

  - name: print content
    debug: msg={{ files.results }} # First item = content of file1 and so on
```