Ansible loop over list object is overwriting attributes
I am trying to loop over a list (spine_list). But my attributes of item1 are getting overwritten by attribute of item2.
Idea is to create an aci spine fabric policy with port block of 1/1, 1/2 and 1/6, 1/7. Playbook is creating 1/1, 1/2 and then immediately overwriting them with 1/6, 1/7 in the second loop.
The set_fact I created is to split the interface id (ex: eth1/6 > 1 6) in order to use them in the Spine Fabric Port Selector Policy task
Could you please suggest what should I do here to avoid such overwrite?
spine_list:
   - nodeid: "1101"
     int_A: "Eth1/1"
     int_B: "Eth1/2"

   - nodeid: "1102"
     int_A: "Eth1/6"
     int_B: "Eth1/7"

Playbook:
    - name: Fetch the interface ID from spine_list 
      set_fact:
        spine_int_B0: "{{ spine_item.int_B.split('/')[0] | regex_replace('(?i)^eth', '') }}"
        spine_int_B1: "{{ spine_item.int_B.split('/')[1] | regex_replace('(?i)^eth', '') }}"
      loop: "{{macsec_spine_list}}"
      loop_control:
           loop_var: spine_item

    - name: Spine Fabric Port Selector Policy
      uri:
        url: "https://{{ apic }}/api/mo/uni.json"
        method: POST
        body_format: json
        validate_certs: no
        headers:
          Cookie: "{{ apic_cookie }}"
          Accept: 'application/json'
        body:
          fabricSpPortP:
            attributes:
              dn: "uni/fabric/spportp-test"
              name: "{{ macsec_policy_names[6].macsec_spine_fabric_ip_policyname }}"
            children:
              - fabricSFPortS:
                  attributes:
                    annotation: ''
                    name: "test2"
                    type: "range"
                  children:
                    - fabricRsSpPortPGrp:
                        attributes:
                          annotation: ''
                          tDn: "uni/fabric/funcprof/spportgrp-test3"
                    - fabricPortBlk:
                        attributes:
                          annotation: ''
                          fromCard: "{{ spine_item.int_A.split('/')[0] | regex_replace('(?i)^eth', '') }}"
                          fromPort: "{{ spine_item.int_A.split('/')[1] | regex_replace('(?i)^eth', '') }}"
                          name: "Block"
                          toCard: "{{ spine_int_B0 }}"
                          toPort: "{{ spine_int_B1 }}"
        return_content: yes
        status_code: [200]
      register: spine_fabric_ps_result
      loop: "{{spine_list}}"
      loop_control:
           loop_var: spine_item


My understanding is that you're taking this the wrong way. You should not call several times your uri in a loop (which overrides the info from previous call in your target API if I believe your description) but you should construct a document (body) containing all the information and call the uri only once. Since I personally have no idea what is the exact yaml/json format expected by you API, I can't give any more precise advice. This is more a question about using your target software than programming so it might be considered off-topic here.

This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512443/register-variables-in-with-items-loop-in-ansible-playbook/29564339#29564339
